# SQL order by any CONSTANT - Why and How Does It Work?

Tags: sql, database, sql-order-by

Why this - order by ANY/RANDOM constant works in SQL (checked on PostgreSQL, MySQL, SqlLite)

```
select * from 
(
    select 1 as id
    union all 
    select 3
    union all 
    select 2
) as A
order by 1=1
-- order by 'a'::text -- this also works
-- order by true -- and this
```

Where is it specified in SQL Standard?
AFAIR everywhere it is specified that after `order by` there should be valid expression within this SELECT (valid column from select- or from- list, or expressions based on that columns and so on),but nowhere I've found just any constant.

P.S. I saw such constructions in Server code where SQL is concatenated due to user selection and `order by 1=1` with comment "disable ordering id user didn't select any column" :)

Comment: That's just the same as `order by true` essentially it doesn't affect the ordering as every row still requires a tie-breaker

Comment: 25 years of SQL, and I've never seen this.  I would have guessed it wouldn't even parse.

Comment: This is valid syntax in some databases eg Mysql, it's a syntax error in SQL Server.

Comment: @Stu, here it works :) - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all 
In my PGSQL as well

Comment: Doesn't parse in Teradata either.  I think this is just a lazy way to allow some sort of dynamic order by clause, so you know you always need an `and `

Comment: I've written an answer with regards to the SQL standard, SQL Server and other DBMS, but unfortunately this request got closed early. This happens rather often on stackoverflow. Sorry. If this request gets re-opened by tomorrow, I'll post my answer.

Comment: The ORDER BY syntax is valid ANSI SQL, using the non-core SQL-2016 feature T031, BOOLEAN data type.

Comment: Back in the day, the ORDER BY items had to be just SELECT list columns. Later non-SELECT list columns became valid, and arbitrary value expressions.

Comment: However, SELECT without a FROM is invalid ANSI SQL.

Comment: You can use https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/ to verify SQL standard syntax.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Its open now

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL allows a list of **value expressions** in `ORDER BY`. This can be a list of columns, but also including something like `a || b` or `a * b` or `upper(a)` or `case when a = b then 1 else 2 end` or even just a constant like `123` or `'abc'`.

Whether a DBMS allows

```
ORDER BY 1 = 1
```

depends on whether the DBMS supports the boolean data type, because 1=1 is true (a boolean value), so the DBMS must accept a boolean in the `ORDER BY` clause. The SQL standard includes the boolean type, but not all DBMS support it.

That SQL Server does not allow

```
ORDER BY 'xyz'
```

i.e. a constant expression, is another thing. It just doesn't, because it makes no sense to order by a constant. They included this check and report an error in case, because they probably saw that this was a common mistake and people were surprised by their unordered query results. This may stem from SQL Server allowing single quotes for alias names, which is not standard compliant, so a typo like

```
SELECT value AS 'price'
FROM mytable
ORDER BY 'prize'
```

would get unnoticed. (A standard-compliant DBMS would raise an error telling us that 'price' is a string literal, not an alias name.)

As to why you see things like

```
ORDER BY 1 = 1
```

at all is that the query may be generated from user input. The part after `ORDER BY` is filled with the columns the user chooses, or some dummy constant in case they don't choose any columns for the ordering at all.